# Django Rest framework 3.4.0, ViewSet with custom create() and Many-to-many relationship

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have the following Django models:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    '''Task needed to complete a goal'''
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Issue(models.Model):
    '''Issue from different forges'''
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    tasks = models.ManyToManyField(Task)
```

I have the following serializers:

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    '''Serializer to represent the Task model'''

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ("id", "title")

class IssueSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    '''Serializer to represent the issue model'''

    tasks = TaskSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Issue
        fields = ("title", "tasks")
```

Now my POST request is the following one:

```
{
  "id": null,
  "title": "",
  "tasks": [14]
}
```

with an empty title for the issue because I'll provide this one server-side  So I need to redefine the create() of the IssueViewSet as follow:

```
class IssueViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    '''ViewSet for viewing and editing Issue objects'''
    queryset = Issue.objects.all().order_by('id')
    serializer_class = IssueSerializer

    def create(self, request):
        serializer = IssueSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            issue = Issue(title='test', tasks=serializer.validated_data['tasks'])
            issue.save()
            return Response({'status': 'issue created'})
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I only have the following errors by now:

```
  File "/views.py", line 32, in create
    issue = Issue(title='test', tasks=serializer.validated_data['tasks'])
KeyError: 'tasks'
```

And indeed it seems serializer.validated_data does not have a tasks key. I'm missing something either defining my serializers or my create().

Answer (score 0):

You marked `tasks` to be `read_only` in `IssueSerializer`. That's why you can't find the `tasks` keys in the `validated_data`.